# Flash button click event

Tags: actionscript-3

I am just confused with flash actionscript. I know PH & C#. Just trying to figure out to make a simple test flash game.

Using flash textbox I wrote some text as "click here" and made a right click on it and chosen "Convert to Symbol" and named it as "startbutton".

I created a second frame (blank frame) and I gave a right click on the first frame (keyframe) and in actionscript.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
stop();
startbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startgame);
function startgame(event:MouseEvent):void{
  nextFrame();
}
```

That's all is my FULL CODE. I really don't even know the header files in ActionScript too. Can anyone correct my code and should I need anymore lines on top or bottom?

The above code's output is keep on blinking. i.e. guess the two frames are keep on repeating.

Comment: In `startgame()`, you can `gotoAndStop(2)` indicating to advance and stop on frame 2 of the timeline.

Comment: @JasonSturges - Tried but found no use.

Answer (score 1):

Create a button instance on the stage:

[image: button]

Give the button control an instance name of `button`:

[image]

Create 2 frames on the timeline:

[image: timeline]

On frame 1, set actions to `stop()` the timeline from playing, and setup an event listener to advance and stop on frame 2 when the button is clicked:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent)
{
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Upon pressing the button it will advance to frame 2 of the timeline and stop.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely didn't name the instance of that button on the stage "startbutton".

Naming the button symbol in the library is not enough. You need to ensure that you have actually named your button instance on the stage.

If you click on that button on the stage and look at the properties panel, you'll see that there is an "instance name" field. Name the instance - "startbutton" and your code should work just fine.